# Is it possible to use client login page instead of identityserver login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

i´m new to identityserver and the security.  I finish all the quickstart in the documentation but all the samples use the identityserver login page. Is it possible to make login page from client website, so it wont redirect from localhost:5003 to localhost:5000 then back again to localhost:5003?

Comment: same problem here. I want to use the form in my web site but the auth from the IS4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword.  See [Protecting an API using Passwords](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html).

You have a form where the user enters their username & password, and then in your code-behind you do something similar to the code found on that page under "Requesting a token using the password grant", substituting "alice" and "password" below with the submitted values.

```
// request token
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.client", "secret");
var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice", "password", "api1");

if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My Client should be a Angular2 Client. So i read the best grant ypes is the implicit. Is there any a possibility to do that? And a second question how does it work with a signup for users? Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: I want to have a Angular 2 Client and a api written in php...whats the best practice for that?

Comment: Normally the login page should be in identity server. This is by design. Notice another port like in your example is another CORS origin in practice, so expect all kind of CORS and frame origin problems. Anyway, I think it was recently done right. See this https://damienbod.com/2017/05/06/secure-asp-net-core-mvc-with-angular-using-identityserver4-openid-connect-hybrid-flow/ least privilege seems to agree